# Statistic that combines proportion and 'success' size

Tags: estimation, proportion

I have proportion data where I am interested in the proportion of successes, but also in the number of successes.  Is there some statistic I can calculate to summarize this info into one number?

Sample data:

```
X   N    P
2   4   .5
40 200  .2
3   10  .3
50 100  .5
```

Here the first and last data have the same proportion, but I would like the statistic to acknowledge the fact there is a lot more confidence in the last line (maybe incorporate the margin of error some how, but I would like it to take into account X not N).

Comment: Because the "confidence" (by almost any definition) depends on $N$, the last parenthetical remark may perhaps be asking for the impossible.  Note, too, that $X$ and $N$ are intimately linked via $X = N P$, so any MoE for $P$ depending on $X$ depends *a fortiori* on $N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't summarize this in one statistic,  But p and N the two binomial parameters tell the story.

Comment: You are correct--and refreshingly to the point--but doesn't the question at least implicitly ask for a way to express "confidence"? And, to take it seriously, we should be able to provide a *quantitative expression* of confidence. Which of the pair $(N, p)$ would you nominate as the confidence?

Comment: Both since the standard error of estimate is √[p(1-p)/N] But if I can take just one it will be N because regardless of pthe standard error is bounded above by 1/[2√N]

Answer (score 2):

I'd compute the proportion (X/N=P) along with a 95% confidence interval for that proportion. The width of that confidence interval shows you the margin of error you want. [Use this free online calculator](http://www.graphpad.com/quickcalcs/ConfInterval1.cfm) to do the math.

Comment: good solution but it again demonstrates that you can't describe this with a single number.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider [shrinkage estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrinkage_estimator) of $P$ given $X$. One straightforward way to do this is, for each row $i$,

$P_{i}^* = m\frac{c}{c+x_i} + \frac{x_i}{n_i}\frac{x_i}{x_i+c}$, where

- $x/n = P$, the proportion of successes
- $x =$ the number of successes
- $m =$ the mean proportion across the whole data set (which, based on the data above, is 0.303)
- $c =$ a scaling constant (the higher this is, the more shrinkage there is)

The intuition is that you are creating a weighted average $P^*$ which shrinks each proportion to the mean on the basis of how many successes it has. The left term establishes the base value, which will be more or less of a factor based on the degree to which $x_i$ differs from $c$. The right term pushes the value from $P_i^*$ away from that average, once again based on how $x_i$ differs from $c$.

The downside if that you have to choose an arbitrary scaling constant $c$. But you can justify this based on how many successes values $x_i$ it would take you to "trust" the proportion estimate $p_i$.

A canonical example of this in action is the [imdb top 250](http://www.imdb.com/chart/top), for which movie ratings are scaled to be higher (or lower, for the [bottom 100](http://www.imdb.com/chart/bottom)) on the basis of how many votes they have.

(By the way, it's not clear to me why you trust entries with high $X$ more than high $N$, but you clearly have more domain-specific knowledge.)